# detect an outlier in multi-dimensions - where the number of rows is not >> number of columns

Tags: pca, outliers, distance, anomaly-detection

I have the following situation: a data frame with two dimensions `x` and `y`, with three "areas": an a-parametric distribution centered around `(1,1)`, one centered around `(3,3)`, and the point `(1,3)`. This point is an outlier only in the `2D` space, and not in either dimension.
In this simple case, it is easy to locate it, e.g. based on distance.

But what if I have, say, 100000 rows and 300 columns (features)? any attempt at a density approximation fails miserably, and a distance calculation is too expensive. Clustering algorithms like `dbscan` think most of the points are noise, and cannot classify them. PCA doesn't really work, because I find that in many of the examples I encountered the dimension cannot be reduced significantly (the contribution to the variance doesn't decrease so fast).

Trying to divide the space into cells fails in this case, too - even if each dimension is homogeneous, and I classify very simple as below or above the median, 2^300 is, well, irrelevant.

I looked at previous Q&A here but didn't really find anything suitable for this kind of dimensions. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

try to implement angle based outlier detection technique-

http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/KDD2008.pdf ( original paper)

Implementation in R with simple explanation-

https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2018/08/anomaly-detection-in-high-dimensional.html

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a very interesting read at least - I like ideas which are based on simple principles. Or like the saying goes: if it is not simple, it will simply not happen :)